# Linking library with cmake C++

Tags: c++, cmake, linker

I'm trying to incorporate libevdev into my project. I cloned the source into a subdirectory in my project and included the given header. But as I want to compile, I get a linker error

```
undefined reference to `libevdev_new_from_fd'
```

I tried to add the following to my CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library (evdevlib libevdev/libevdev/libevdev.c)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} evdevlib)
```

but now its missing some config.h. What am I missing?

Comment: Is `libevdev` present in the project source directory? If not, provide the complete path and then try to build.

Comment: According to the source tree, `libevdev` consist from more than single source file. Just build and install the library using build system it naturally supports (autotools). Then, as the library provides `.pc` file, you may use this library with [pkg_check_modules](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/FindPkgConfig.html?highlight=pkg_check_modules#command:pkg_check_modules) call.