# Device input event using libevdev in C++

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, touchscreen, touch-event, evdev

I am trying to get the touch event from Raspberry Pi Touchscreen. I made it work using FT5406 driver in python and evtest in C. However, I want to write code for this in C++. I notice **libevdev** is very useful in C, but when I call it in C++, like

```
#include <libevdev/libevdev.h>
```

it will always give me

```
Fatal error: libevdev/libevdev.h: No such file or directory
```

I manually install libevdev and save it under the path of my code and provide complete path of that library, but the same thing happens.

I also try the method according to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848600/linking-library-with-cmake-c), the problem is still here.

I already installed the corresponding package:

```
sudo apt-get install libevdev-dev
sudo apt-get install libudev-dev
```

Is anyone can help me out???

Comment: How are you compiling the code?

Comment: show your Makefile

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same problem.  Just find the proper path to the header file.

```
sudo find / -name libevdev.h
```

Then include the path starting from the include directory.  Mine was:

```
/usr/include/libevdev-1.0/libevdev/libevdev.h
```

So my include line was:

```
#include <libevdev-1.0/libevdev/libevdev.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

It all depends how you setup your include search paths, as using `#include <my_file>` won't search the current directory. You'd have to use `#include "my_file"` for that.

Anyway, don't bother copying to you current directory, simply supply the correct paths.

```
gcc my_code.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs libevdev)
```

Where pkg-config will expand to something like -I/usr/include/libevdev-1.0/ -levdev, where libev-dev-1.0 has a subfolder libevdev.